# Where do I put statis ENV variables in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

I currently have the following in my application_controller, but this seems the incorrect way to do this, considering these variables will only be set one time and will not change throughout the servers lifetime?

application_controller.rb

```
  def self.flavor
    @flavor ||= MyApp::Application.config.flavor
  end
```

application.rb

```
config.flavor          = ENV['FLAVOR']
```

Is there a better place to put this in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of thing should be in an [initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files).

In the initializer, load the value from your environment variables and set a constant.

```
FLAVOR = ENV['FLAVOR']
```

Then use the constant in your `application_controller.rb` file.

```
def self.flavor
    @flavor ||= FLAVOR
end
```